# How to modify a message in Spring Integration after it's received by a queue so it's changed before going on to another queue?

Tags: java, spring-integration, message

I'm trying to write a program that sends a message (json) to a queue, modifies that message by adding another property to it, and then sending the modified message on to a second queue. I'm fine with having a class to do the modification, but I'm wondering what the best technique is in spring integration to do this. I'm currently trying with a service activator, but getting lots of problems.

The message going from the first queue to the second queue is configured in xml so there is no explicit call to send the message on in my Main method.

Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: Closed as unclear. You should be more specific and share some code with words "I tried this and that and want this, but get that". You can't modify message in the queue. That is not what they are designed for

Comment: Btw there is `Content Enricher` pattern for adding properties: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.10.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-transformation-chapter.html#content-enricher. And yes, no body here is going to code for you